# ng repeat not says column undefined

Tags: html, angularjs, forms, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have beens struggling for past 4 hours over this now ! :D

the problem is that I am trying to build a form and dynamically taking rows, with input texts. like this :

```
</div>
                <a ng-click="add_row()" id="add_row(colname,coltype)" class="btn btn-success pull-left">Add Row</a><a ng-click="delete_row()" id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-danger">Delete Row</a>
              </div>
```

Well this is my entire html table + buttons :

```
<div class="col-md-12 column">
                    <table class="table table-striped" id="tab_logic" >
                      <colgroup>
                        <col span="1" style="width: 5%;">
                        <col span="1" style="width: 45%;">
                        <col span="1" style="width: 50%;">
                      </colgroup>
                      <thead>
                        <tr >
                          <th class="text-center">
                              #
                          </th>
                          <th class="text-center">
                              Column Name
                          </th>
                          <th class="text-center">
                              Column Type
                          </th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr id='addr0'>
                          <td class="text-center">
                              1
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            Column Name
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            Column Type
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr ng-repeat="col in cols">
                          <tr id='addr1'></tr>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <a ng-click="add_row(colname,coltype)" id="add_row" class="btn btn-success pull-left">Add Row</a><a ng-click="delete_row()" id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-danger">Delete Row</a>
              </div>
```

and my js part being :

```
$scope.cols = { colnames: [] , coltypes: [] };
   var i=1;
  $scope.add_row = function(colname,coltype) {
      $('#addr'+i).html("<td class='text-center'>"+ (i+1) +"</td><td><input ng-repeat='colname in cols.colnames track by $index'  data-ng-model='colname' name='colname"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='New Column Name'  class='form-control'></td><td><input ng-repeat='coltype in cols.coltypes track by $index'  data-ng-model='coltype' name='coltype"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='New Column Type'  class='form-control'></td>");
      $scope.cols.colnames.push({colname:$scope.colname});
      $scope.cols.coltypes.push({coltype:$scope.coltype });
      $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
      i++; 
  }
  $scope.delete_row = function() {
         if(i>1){
         $("#addr"+(i-1)).html('');
         i--;
         }
  }
```

So you see, it is dynamically generating an inner html. Now the problem is that these colnames and coltypes are not getting reflected In fact what I see in the json being posted via some $http call is "undefined".

Kindly let me know have real struggled long on this one, all in vain.

TIA!

Comment: this isn't the intended way to use angular as designed.  in angular, you should strive to work with your data, and allow angular to deal with the DOM.  any time you use another library, like jquery in this case, to modify the DOM, you are in territory where angular can't keep two way bindings up to date without exceptional work, which defeats most of the purpose of using angular.

Comment: basically, you really should avoid changing the innerHTML values when using angular.  if you can't work out a way to solve your problem without this kind of logic, then you generally would need to add your HTML modifying code into a custom directive.

Comment: yes I understand, but I have to add a row all the time. so inserting the inner HTML, I am no good at javascript, hardly started experimenting with it a few days back

Comment: your code really doesn't make sense.  why when you try to create a new row are you adding a new `ng-repeat`?  the better way to do this would be to have an `ng-repeat` that loops through an array, and the `add_row` button simply inserts a new element in the array, which the `ng-repeat` dynamically renders.  no inner html changes necessary.

Comment: @Claies, I have updated it, sorry I am handling any frontend the very first time in my life :D

Comment: what are `colname` and `coltype` set to? do you have some UI element that you aren't showing that is setting these values?

Comment: the logic you are trying to use here just plain won't work.

Comment: lol, why? I am not asking for spoon feeding but why wont it work :(

Comment: it's not the angular way at all.  also, you still haven't provided complete code;  it won't be possible to show you a working solution until you show where `colname` and `coltype` are defined, and some sort of example data with expected result would help as well.  Please see how to create a [mcve]

Comment: i don't now why it can't work for you and for me. [have you tried this](https://jsbin.com/loxocibeku/edit?html,output)?

Comment: Yes have tried it, I am actively commenting on your answers. the colname and coltype being input are all undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to handle this kind of code with angular is to adjust the array that holds your data, and allow angular to render the data.  There is no need to manipulate the HTML.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.cols = [{}];

  $scope.add_row = function() {
    $scope.cols.push({});
  };

  $scope.delete_row = function(row) {
    $scope.cols.splice(row, 1);
  };

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <table>
    <colgroup>
      <col span="1" style="width: 5%;" />
      <col span="1" style="width: 45%;" />
      <col span="1" style="width: 45%;" />
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="text-center">
          #
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
          Column Name
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
          Column Type
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="col in cols track by $index">
        <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
        <td>
          <input ng-model="col.colname">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input ng-model="col.coltype"><a href="" ng-click="delete_row($index)">Delete</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <a href="" ng-click="add_row()">Add New Row</a>

  <div ng-repeat="col in cols">
    {{$index}} - {{col.colname}} - {{col.coltype}}
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see, our angular code simply adds an empty row to the array on add, and splices the row at the specific `$index` on delete.  Angular is able to add the appropriate properties to the objects in each row as necessary.

http://plnkr.co/edit/L2HwAIiR13dectc5QmCJ?p=preview

Comment: haha, well that works in your demo, but I am rendering this with a tornado server, so it throws this error to me :   File "index_html.generated.py", line 5
    _tt_tmp = $index+1  # index.html:135
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I don't have any code at all that is assigning `$index + 1` to a variable.... `$index` is a special angular construct, there is no `$index` on the server... it seems like now you might need to show what you are trying to do server side, because my example shows how this is done using angular by not doing anything at all server side.

Comment: If I had to *guess* at your error, it probably is because the server and angular both want to use `{{ }}` for expressions.  you will likely need to change one or the other to use something else, but that's a different question topic, which has been asked and answered many times here already.

Comment: you could also use `ng-bind` instead of `{{ }}`, but it is a bit less flexible.

Comment: ng-bind how?ng-bind="index" ? or "$index" ? and how about $index + 1 with ng bind?

Comment: you can put anything that would be an expression inside `ng-bind`. so `ng-bind="$index+1"` would work.  at this point, it seems like you might need to spend some more time studying the basics about how angular works, since it feels really hard to answer a question when every piece of code has to be explained.....

Answer (score 0):

You wrote wrong syntax. Please correct it.

```
<a ng-click="add_row(colname,coltype)" id="add_row" class="btn btn-success pull-left">Add Row</a><a ng-click="delete_row()" id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-danger">Delete Row</a>
```

Please check this code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ctrl">
<div class="col-md-12 column">
                    <table class="table table-striped" id="tab_logic" >
                      <colgroup>
                        <col span="1" style="width: 5%;">
                        <col span="1" style="width: 45%;">
                        <col span="1" style="width: 50%;">
                      </colgroup>
                      <thead>
                        <tr >
                          <th class="text-center">
                              #
                          </th>
                          <th class="text-center">
                              Column Name
                          </th>
                          <th class="text-center">
                              Column Type
                          </th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="col in cols">
                          <td>{{$index}}</td>
                          <td><input placeholder="Column name" ng-model="col.colname" /></td>
                          <td><input placeholder="Column type" ng-model="col.coltype" /></td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <a ng-click="add_row()" id="add_row" class="btn btn-success pull-left">Add Row</a><a ng-click="delete_row()" id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-danger">Delete Row</a>
              </div>
<script>
  angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope){
    $scope.cols = [];
    $scope.add_row = function() {
      $scope.cols.push({colname: '', coltype: ''});
    }
    $scope.delete_row = function() {
      $scope.cols.splice($scope.cols.length - 1, 1)
    }
  })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No man, still doesnt help. undefined. is the colname and undefined is the coltype.

Comment: Please show your ng-repeat statement? You said ng-repeat problem but you didn't show it.

Comment: man I am a fool, I am updating it, and I am using ng-repeat every where I could :D I m so sorry, updating in a while.

Comment: You have many mistake in here. Why you use jquery to append to table while angular ng-repeat can do that. And where the colname and coltype define?

Comment: How do I do it then? adding a new row, and whatever is input I post that without using jquery?

Comment: Tell we know your goal?

Comment: man, I just want to make something like : [ ] [ ] [ ] these three cells in a row. and then an add row delete row and then these inputs go as a list of jsons or whatever datatype. say like input your fav country and its capital. so a users all fav countries and capitals are persisted and posted else where via $http post.

Comment: with the current code , I am getting it all well but it is undefined undefined always. for coltype and colname

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues. First of all you are doing **ng-repeat** on cols it's an **object** I removed jquery to make it more simple and using **corejs** and **angular** only to achieve this. using **ng-repeat** on ***input*** type and get value from each input you need to do like this **ng-model="cols.colnames[$index]"** and same for coltype **ng-model="cols.coltypes[$index]"**. **Try this code for keeping angular simple**!

```
    <div class="col-md-12 column" ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
        <table class="table table-striped" id="tab_logic">
            <colgroup>
                <col span="1" style="width: 50%;">
                    <col span="1" style="width: 50%;">
            </colgroup>
            <thead>
                <tr>

                    <th class="text-center">
                        Column Name
                    </th>
                    <th class="text-center">
                        Column Type
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class='text-center'>
                        <input class='form-control' name='coltype"+i+"' ng-repeat="colname in cols.colnames track by $index" type="text" ng-model="cols.colnames[$index]">{{colName}}
                    </td>
                    <td class='text-center'>
                        <input class='form-control' name='coltype"+i+"' ng-repeat="colname in cols.coltypes track by $index" type="text" ng-model="cols.coltypes[$index]">{{colName}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div>
            <a ng-click="add_row()" id="add_row" class="btn btn-success pull-left">Add Row</a>
            <a ng-click="delete_row()" class="pull-right btn btn-danger">Delete Row</a>
        </div>
    </div>

 <script>
      angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope){
        $scope.cols = { colnames: [] , coltypes: [] };
        console.log($scope.cols)
       var i=1;
      $scope.add_row = function(colname,coltype) {
          $scope.cols.colnames.push($scope.colName);
          $scope.cols.coltypes.push($scope.coltype);
        console.log($scope.cols.colname)   
      }
      $scope.delete_row = function() {
             $scope.cols.colnames.pop();
               $scope.cols.coltypes.pop();         
      }
      })

</script>
```

Comment: <div>
  <td><input ng-repeat='colname in cols.colnames track by $index'  data-ng-model='colname' name='colname"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='New Column Name'  class='form-control'></td><td><input ng-repeat='coltype in cols.coltypes track by $index'  data-ng-model='coltype' name='coltype"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='New Column Type'  class='form-control'></td>
   <a ng-click="add_row(colname,coltype)" id="add_row" class="btn btn-success pull-left">Add Row</a><a ng-click="delete_row()" id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-danger">Delete Row</a>
  </div> why this?

Comment: I mean basically why am I adding that thing twice, as per you? the 1st snippet whereas it is also present in $('#addr'+i).html too.

Comment: Jorawar this looks close though but it is still not working, where to add what html and all?

Comment: when you app loads to browser $scope.coltype and $scope.colename does not exist. that's why they are undefined when you try to add row they need to exist before you can use addrow method.

Comment: try it now it should work for you too if it works for me [try here](https://jsbin.com/loxocibeku/edit?html,output)

Comment: Man, i think I was here before, it still gives undefined. see the changes I am updating shortly. why are the colnames and coltypes coming out undefined? :(

Comment: <tr ng-repeat="col in cols">
                          <tr id='addr1'></tr>
                        </tr> Why is this here? col in cols is just two empty lists isn t it?

Comment: I just removed that, it is still still undefined. this is the response I am getting :"cols": {"coltypes": [{}, {}], "colnames": [{}, {}]} I just do data.cols = $scope.cols; and finally http post the data thenafter.

Comment: Jorawar, did you try to print the contents of col too? as some debug or something. or maybe I can do that.

Comment: No wonder it is inserting the objects, but is inserting all nulls, or undefined ones. I think the coltype  / colname value itself is nt getting passed at all.

Comment: try it now, i have removed jquery and used only angular and core js to do it.